# How to change script to work with more tabs than 9

Tags: jquery, joomla

I had modification of script for tabs on my site and it works fine, untill there is tabs less than 9.

When I add more than 10 it stop working any idea how to modify this? to work not only with tabs like #sppb-tab1-1 or #sppb-tab1-9 but also with #sppb-tab1-12

```js
jQuery(function() {
  const parent = "sppb-addon-1539203446310";
  const links = jQuery("#" + parent + " .custom-tab li a");
  let counter = 1;

  for (let x = 0; x < links.length; x++) {
    let newID = jQuery(".custom-tab li a").eq(x).attr('id').slice(0, -1) + counter;
    let newLink = jQuery(".custom-tab li a").eq(x).attr('href').slice(0, -1) + counter;
    if (jQuery(".custom-tab li a").eq(x).attr('href').slice(0, -1) == "#sppb-tab1-1") {
      newLink = jQuery(".custom-tab li a").eq(x).attr('href').slice(0, -2) + counter;
    }
    jQuery(".custom-tab li a").eq(x).attr('href', newLink);
    jQuery(".custom-tab li a").eq(x).attr('id', newID);
    jQuery(".custom-tab li a").eq(x).attr('aria-controls', newLink);
    counter++;
  }

  // Tabs to switch it off
  jQuery(".sppb-tab-1539203446310").click(function() {
    return false
  })

  jQuery(".sppb-tab-1539203446313").click(function() {
    return false
  })
})
```

Comment: Just use an `each()` loop through all the `.custom-tab li a` elements. Then it doesn't matter how many there are

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `each()` loop through all the `.custom-tab li a` elements. Then it doesn't matter how many there are. Something like this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  const parent = "sppb-addon-1539203446310";
  const links = $("#" + parent + " .custom-tab li a");

  $('.custom-tab li a').each(function(i) {
    let newID = this.id.slice(0, -1) + (i + 1);
    let newLink = this.href.slice(0, -1) + (i + 1);
    if (this.href.slice(0, -1) == "#sppb-tab1-1")
      newLink = this.href.slice(0, -2) + (i + 1);

    $(this).attr({
      href: newLink,
      id: newID,
      'aria-controls': newLink
    });
  });

  // Tabs to switch it off
  $(".sppb-tab-1539203446310, .sppb-tab-1539203446313").click(function() {
    return false
  })
});
```

A couple of notes on this. Firstly, it's good practice for performance reasons to create a single instance of a jQuery object and re-use it, although in this case you only need a single one as you can update multiple attributes at once by providing an object to `attr()`.

Secondly, I'd suggest not using incremental `id` attributes as it's often an anti-pattern. Using a single common class on all the elements along with DOM traversal to relate them to each other when needed is often a much better solution.

Comment: Thx for help, right now when I have tab with link #sppb-tab1-10 it change it to #sppb-tab1-19 :(

Comment: Please add an example of your HTML to the question.